# Enabling the Dark Keyboard for iOS Devices with HTML Tags

Tags: html, ios, css, wkwebview

Is there any way to change the code of an HTML textfield (for example) to make the dark keyboard appear instead of the light keyboard.

I know this used to be possible in older versions of iOS, but I haven't seen anything on it recently. I've done some research and not even the old documentation is turning up.

For this specific case, I am attempting to do this with the WKWebView.

Thanks!